# NoMethodError In Ruby

Tags: ruby, sinatra, nomethoderror

I have a bit of ruby code:

```
def createCal(cal)
    mod = @on + @off #line creating error.
    @daycount = 0       
    cal
  end
```

This generates the following error: NoMethodError at /calendar undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass file: main.rb location: createCal line: 83

I am using this in Sinatra, and so I can print out @on and @off onto a webpage and I can confirm that they are in fact being loaded with values. I also do a '@ooo = @on + @off' in my haml template and that produces 7, which is to be expected because on is 4 and off 3.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Here's how I'm handling @on and @off

```
post '/calendar' do
  @on = params["on"]
  @off = params["off"]
  @date = params["date"]
  a = Doer.new
  @var = a.makeDate(@date)
  @on = @on.to_i
  @off = @off.to_i
  @ooo = @on + @off
  @cal = a.makeCal(@var)
  haml :feeling
end
```

Comment: It reminds me of [a question I asked some time ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970645/object-with-bigdecimals-returns-empty-strings-on-to-s). I was wondering why I couldn't get my attributes in Rails. Now I don't know too much about Sinatra, but are `on` and `off` supposed to be called using methods `on` and `off` instead of `@on` and `@off`? Because it looks like your variables/attributes aren't pulled right when it says they return `nil`...

Comment: Upvoted to counter the down vote which I don't think was justified as this is a perfectly valid question.

Comment: I don't think they should be methods. They are just variables I'm pulling in from a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing two different instance variables:

- The `@on` in `post` is an instance variable for your Sinatra instance.
- The `@on` in `createCal` is an instance variable from your *Doer* instance.

To use `@on` and `@off` like you want, you'll need to change them into arguments passed to the `createCal` method. Something like this:

```
class Doer
  def createCal(cal, on, off)
    mod = on + off
    # more code...
    cal
  end
end

post '/calendar' do
  a = Doer.new
  date = a.makeDate params['date']
  @cal = a.makeCal date, params['on'], params['off']

  haml :some_template
end
```

Comment: mod creates the modulus value I use later.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. Updated my example with some better allusions to the hand-waving going on.

Comment: Thanks. This worked, and I actually cleaned up my /calendar so that the makeDate method is called inside my makeCal method. I don't know if that is better or worse.

Comment: That is **much** better. Think about it from someone else's point-of-view, using your code: I just need a calendar from X to Y, just tell me how to send you those dates, I don't care how it works inside.

Answer (score 1):

Your instance variables probably aren't in the scope of the method.  Try the following to test this theory:

```
def createCal(cal, on, off, daycount)
  mod = on + off #line creating error.
  daycount = 0       
  cal
end
```

And call it (in your /calendar block) with:

```
createCal(cal, @on, @off, @daycount)
```

Comment: I tried doing exactly that earlier. However, I tried it again just to make sure I wasn't missing something. The same thing error, linenumber, etc occur again.

Comment: Can you post all the relevant code on github/ in a gist/pastie and provide a sample url that you are testing on and I'll check it out.

Comment: Sorry, I meant what URL locally, as in /calendar?on=5&off=200 etc.

Comment: /calendar?on=3&off=4&date=9/12/2011 something like that.

Comment: After checking out your gist, it is definitely a scope issue.  Check out https://gist.github.com/1198898 which works.  Look at what I did to your post /calendar block.

Comment: Agreed, the instance variables in the controller are not instance methods in the Doer class instance

Comment: https://gist.github.com/1198898 - This should do what you want.  I have moves @on and @off to the Doer class.  You may need to make some slight changes if you want those values passed through to the template.  You will simply need `@on = a.on; @off = a.off`